# Excel VBA subscript out of range while referencing table

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting "subscript out of range" error when trying to reference a particular table. The report I'm pulling from always has a sheet named "TbNEXOutageEvent" and this sheet always has a table named "NEXOutageEvent_1" but for some reason my code keeps failing at the last line shown below. I have more code beyond what is shown, but this last line (set raw_tbl =...) is where the error keeps popping up. Using Office 365. I feel like I must be missing something simple... Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Sub raw2processed(rawTable As String, processedTable As String) 'modified from stackoverflow user11198948

Dim lc As Long, _
mc As Variant, x As Variant, _
raw_data As Worksheet, processed_data As Worksheet, _
raw_workbook As Workbook, processed_workbook As Workbook, _
raw_tbl As ListObject, processed_tbl As ListObject

Select Case rawTable
    Case "Data Input"
        Set raw_workbook = ThisWorkbook
        Set raw_data = raw_workbook.Worksheets("Data Input")
        Set processed_data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Notes")
        Set raw_tbl = raw_data.ListObjects("Table1")
        Set processed_tbl = processed_data.ListObjects("Table2")
    Case "TbNEXOutageEvent"
        Dim src As Range, findRange As Range, rng2 As Range, _
            cName As Variant, _
            i As Long
            
        cName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Report", _
            filefilter:="Excel Workbooks(*.xls*),*.xls*")
            
        Set raw_workbook = Workbooks.Open(cName)
        Set raw_data = raw_workbook.Worksheets("TbNEXOutageEvent")
        Set processed_data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Input")
        'Set src = raw_data.Range("A5").CurrentRegion'removed due to table is already created
        'raw_data.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=src, _
            xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, tablestyleName:="TableStyleMedium28").Name = "NEX_Data"'removed due to table is already created
        Set raw_tbl = raw_data.ListObjects("NEXOutageEvent_1")
```

Comment: Try adding `For Each lo in raw_data.ListObjects: Debug.Print lo.Name: Next lo`  before the problem line. Is the output what you expect?

Comment: Well that's odd, it's labeled as "NEXOutageEvent_1" in the name manager and when i select the table, but your suggestion produces "NEXOutageEvent" - this seemed to correct the issue, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned the error pops up at the

```
Set raw_tbl = raw_data.ListObjects("NEXOutageEvent_1")
```

Table "NEXOutageEvent_1" does not exist on the specified worksheet at the time the code is running.
I woud try below, if there's only one table in the "TbNEXOutageEvent" worksheet.

```
 Set raw_tbl = raw_data.ListObjects(1)
```

Comment: That's what I thought was causing the error as well, confirmed with Tim Williams' suggestion. Unfortunately I don't know that this will always be the only table, or which ID it will have, since this is a monthly report that consists of several sheets and thousands of lines of data. At least now I'm able to move further with the code, thanks both of you.